# Stop webview loading when navigating

Tags: ios, image, webview

Basically I have a webview that when clicking certain file extensions will open a new view controller to view the image. In iOS 6 [webView stopLoading] worked perfectly in stopping the webview to pass the view controller.

Since upgrading to iOS 7, this will only work once or twice but then it will open said image in the webview AND pass the view controller.

Below is what I was working with previously in IOS 6.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
///////////////
//IMAGE CODE///
///////////////
                //Image file links
                NSURL *imageURl = [request URL];
                NSString *imageFileExtension = [[imageURl absoluteString] pathExtension];

                //Image file extensions
                NSLog(@"fileExtension is: %@", imageFileExtension);
                if ([imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"png"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpg"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpeg"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"gif"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"bmp"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"raw"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"PNG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"JPG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"JPEG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"GIF"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"BMP"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"RAW"]) {

                    [webView stopLoading];
                    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

                    //Image manager
                    WebImageViewController * vc = [[WebImageViewController alloc] initWithURL:[request URL]];
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
                    [vc release];

                }else{

                    //Image file links
                    NSURL *imageURl = [request URL];
                    NSString *imageFileExtension = [imageURl pathExtension];

                    //Image file extensions
                    NSLog(@"fileExtension is: %@", imageFileExtension);
                if ([imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"png"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpg"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpeg"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"gif"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"bmp"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"raw"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"PNG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"JPG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"JPEG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"GIF"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"BMP"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"RAW"]) {                        

                    [webView stopLoading];
                    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

                    //Image manager
                    WebImageViewController * vc = [[WebImageViewController alloc] initWithURL:[request URL]];
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
                    [vc release];

                    }else{

                    //Image file links
                    NSURL *imageURl = [request URL];
                    NSString *imageFileExtension = [imageURl absoluteString];

                    //Image file extensions
                    NSLog(@"fileExtension is: %@", imageFileExtension);
                if ([imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"png"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpg"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"jpeg"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"gif"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"bmp"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"raw"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"PNG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"JPG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"JPEG"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"GIF"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"BMP"] || [imageFileExtension hasSuffix:@"RAW"]) {                            

                    [webView stopLoading];
                    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

                    //Image manager
                    WebImageViewController * vc = [[WebImageViewController alloc] initWithURL:[request URL]];
                    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
                    [vc release];
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think I managed to get this working. With some re-coding and adjustments i came up with this:

```
        NSURL *imageURl = [request URL];
        NSString *imageFileExtension = [[imageURl absoluteString] pathExtension];

        NSSet *supportedFileExtensions = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"png", @"jpg", @"jpeg", @"gif", @"bmp", @"pdf", @"raw", nil];

        if ([supportedFileExtensions containsObject:[imageFileExtension lowercaseString]]) {

            [webView stopLoading];

            //Image manager
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

            WebImageViewController * vc = [[WebImageViewController alloc] initWithURL:[request URL]];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
            [vc release];
```